# User Input Symbol and time frame Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I got it so far that I can select a ticker and a timeframe into the UI of TradingView.(input.symbol, input.timeframe). But this doesn't change the chart I am in in TradingView.

For example if I am at the ticker SPY and I select BTC/USDT, the chart doesn't go to BTC/USDT. Same goes for the timeframe. Is this possible within Pine Script?

Answer (score 0):

input.symbol and input.timeframe aren't supposed to change the charts settings but to plot respectively a different symbol and timeframe on a chart set on a different symbol and timeframe

Meaning, you can use for example input.symbol for your SPY calculations but on a BTC/USDT chart

Makes sense?